# When i press the mouse left button once it prints too many times

Tags: python-3.x

This is the code i use, can someone help me fix it?

```
import mouse
x = 0
while True:
   if mouse.is_pressed("left"):
       x = x+1
       print(x)
```

the output is this

```
================== RESTART: C:\Users\Liam\Desktop\cps.py==================
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is looping through and picking up the "left" mouse click at a very fast clip.  As long as the mouse button is pressed, the counter was getting incremented and printed.  On my system, the count got up to 5000 before I had released the mouse button.

One thing that you might do is set on an event indicator or flag variable to suppress additional incrementing until the mouse is clicked again.  Following is some additional code I added to your program to provide control of pressing and releasing the mouse button.

```
import mouse
x = 0
y = 1  # Added this to control execution of the "while" loop(s)

while x < 8:    # Arbitrary limit of eight clicks for testing.
    while y == 1:
        if mouse.is_pressed("left"):
            x = x+1
            print(x)
            y = 0   # This shuts down the counter until the mouse button is released
    while y == 0:
        if not mouse.is_pressed("left"):
            y == 1  # Resets the flag so that additional mouse clicks can be counted
```

Testing this out, I got the following simple output to the terminal.

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
```

After the eighth mouse click the program ended.

Hope that provides some ideas for you.

Regards.